# spring JPA not adding double quotes to H2 select query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, h2

My configuration:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;SCHEMA=public;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;
```

JPA generates the following QUERY:

```
select itement0_.id as id1_0_, itement0_.brand as brand2_0_, itement0_._item_id as item3_0_, itement0_.product_group as product_4_0_ from public.item itement0_ where itement0_.item_id=? [42102-200]
```

which blows up with

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ITEM" not found; SQL statement
```

As far I can tell problem is h2 expect public schema in double quotes, so the following query works fine from h2 console:

```
    select itement0_.id as id1_0_, itement0_.brand as brand2_0_, itement0_._item_id as item3_0_, itement0_.product_group as product_4_0_ from "public".item itement0_ where itement0_.item_id=? [42102-200]
```

My Entity:

```
@Getter
@Entity(name = "item")
@Table(name="item", schema = "public")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)

public class ItemEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="UUID")
private final UUID id;

@NotNull
@Column(unique = true)
private final String itemId;

private final String productGroup;

private final String brand;

}
```

Flyway creation script:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item
(
    id            uuid,
    item_id       VARCHAR,
    product_group VARCHAR,
    brand         VARCHAR,
    constraint pk_item PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

result structure in h2:
[image: result structure in h2]

Does anyone know some workaround?

Comment: Are tables created successfully ? How are tables created - Ideally from a SQL file which contains DDL and initial master data load statements

Comment: we use flyway script to crate them manually

Comment: sorry not being specific, yes they are 100%created using flyway script and they have the correct name

Answer (score 6):

You can add hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers parameter to your application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for magical flag! Unfortunately that's not working, it's wrapping all identifiers into double quotes which h2 also does not like: 

from "public".item is working
from public.item is not working
from "public"."item" is not working either

Comment: Then your table item is not there. How do you create the tables?

Comment: It is there we use flyway to create them. Like I said it works fine from h2 console

Comment: It means that you actually have a table `"public"."ITEM"` with lower case schema name and upper case table name. Unquoted identifiers are converted to upper case by default.

Comment: How does your create table statement look like?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli hi, I updated the original question! :)